Can we increase performance of a pythonshell script which is executed in AWS GLUE by increasing maximum workers
I am executing a pure pythonshell script to move some files from one location to another using awa glue... If I increases the max worker nodes in the glue job, will it increase the performance of the job?
Currently the job is taking too much time for the completion.. I would like to improve the performance...please note that I can only update the configuration but not code
